# JDOM Parser and Namespace how to get clean Content

Tags: xml, jdom

MY xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company xmlns="http://www.xx.com/xx">
    <staff>
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company> 




 Reader in = new StringReader(message);
            Document document = (Document)saxBuilder.build(in);
            Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
            List<?> list = rootNode.getChildren("staff", Namespace.getNamespace("xmlns="http://www.infonova.com/MediationFeed""));

            XMLOutputter outp = new XMLOutputter();
            outp.setFormat(Format.getCompactFormat());

            for (int ii = 0; ii < list.size(); ii++) {
                Element node = (Element)list.get(ii);                 

                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                outp.output(node.getContent(), sw);
                StringBuffer sb = sw.getBuffer();

                String xml = sb.toString();
            }
```

but my `xml` object looks like this

```
 <firstname xmlns="http://www.xx.com/xx">yong</firstname>
            <lastname xmlns="http://www.xx.com/xx">mook kim</lastname>
            <nickname xmlns="http://www.xx.com/xx">mkyong</nickname>
            <salary xmlns="http://www.xx.com/xx">100000</salary>
```

every elemnt has namespace. why this? i don't want namespace... I want the same output as is in xml example like

```
<firstname>yong</firstname>
            <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
            <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
            <salary>100000</salary>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the correct results. All those elements started off with the namespace 'http://www.xx.com/xx' so it makes sense that they keep it when you output the Elements. Note, in XML, that the default namespace (the one without a prefix) is applied to all elements that are descendants but which have not redefined the default namespaces themselves.

If this seems like a complicated explaination, try the namespace specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/ or the namespace tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

If you do not want to have the namespaces on these Elements you can remove them with:

```
node.setNamespace(Namespace.NO_NAMESPACE);
```

Rolf

Comment: i try this code but namespaces are still there. when i use String xml = sb.toString(); i still see namespaces...

Answer (score 0):

You must comprehend the difference between XML (in its textual form) and a tree of Nodes. In the tree, there is no such thing as inherited or default namespace: every element node has its own namespace, regardless and independent of the namespace of its ancestor. To achieve what you want, you must change the namespace of *all* element nodes. In your case, iterate through the list returned by getContent() and set the namespace for each element to NO_NAMESPACE.